# My strange proof of the fact that $k[\mathbb P^n]=k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f\in k[\mathbb P^n]$, i.e. $f: \mathbb P^n \to \mathbb A^1$ be a regular function. My purpose is to show $f$ is constant. First $\mathbb A^1$is considered the subset $\{x=[x_0：x_1]\in \mathbb P^1: x_0\neq0 \}$ of $\mathbb P^1$ via the inclusion map $\iota:y \mapsto [1:y]$. Then, $$\bar f = \iota \circ f: \mathbb P^n \to \mathbb P^1, x\mapsto [1:f(x)]$$ is still regular. Now I quote a definition of regular maps between quasiprojective varieties in *Basic Algebraic Geometry 1*, by Shafarevich(page 48):

> **Definition** A regular map $f:X(\subset\mathbb P^n)\to \mathbb P^m$ of an irreducible quasiprojective variety $X$ to projective space
>   $\mathbb P^m$ is given by am (m+1)-tuple of homogeneous
>   polynomials$$[F_0:\cdots:F_m]$$ of the same degree in the homogeneous
>   coordinates of $x\in \mathbb P^n$. We require that for every $x\in X$
>   there exists such an expression for $f$ that $F_i(x)\neq0$ for at
>   least one $i$.

According to this definition, we must have $degf = deg1=0$, and thus $f$ is a constant polynomial. And, the proof would be similar if $\mathbb P^n$ here is replaced by an irreducible projective variety $X$. $\Box$

However,it is very possible that I made some mistakes here, as the standard proof of $k[X]=k$ ($X$ is an irreducible projective variety) is very different(e.g. see page 59 in *Basic Algebraic Geometry 1*, by Shafarevich). Please help.

Comment: I think that it's correct, but that it's hiding a lot. In particular, I think that if one *defines* a regular morphism in the usual way, that it affine locally looks like polynomials, then verifying that this definition agrees with yours for projective varieties is strictly stronger than the statement that $k[X]=k$. So, I don't know which comes first, but, to me, this seems a little circular. In particular if you define morphisms as being locally polynomial its obvious that maps to $\mathbb{A}^1$ are global sections. If you define it as in your definition it's not so clear.

Comment: Does your argument suggest that there are no nonconstant functions on any quasi projective variety?

Comment: you have to prove that your $f$ is indeed a polynomial. By your argument you only proved that $f$ is $g/h$ where $g,h$ are homogeneous polynomials with same degree.

Comment: @ChenJiang I think you are right. Thanks.